# Spliting a text using json parser in java

Tags: java, json

I have few lines of strings in my property file i need to import it and split those lines and use it the way i want

Example format of my property file

```
007.customerclass = component:keyboard;determinantType:key;determinant:test;waste
008.ReasonClass = component:mouse;determinantType:click;determinant:rest;RClass
```

I need to split the entire 007 line and 008 into 4 different parts .
Expected output : keyboard key test waste and mouse click rest RClass

I have achieved this using `split` but i want to achieve it using `jsonparser` to minimize my code

Thank you

Comment: i don't think this is a valid JSON format, so you may not be able to use JsonParser

Comment: this is not a JSON format

Comment: can you please help me with the format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a valid JSON format. However, you can work it out this way:

```
String propertyValue = "component:keyboard;determinantType:key;determinant:test;waste";

// tokenize the input string with the separator
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(test, ";");

// get the tokens and replace the unwanted part
String component = tokenizer.nextToken().replaceAll("component:", "");
String determinantType = tokenizer.nextToken().replaceAll("determinantType:","");
String determinant = tokenizer.nextToken().replaceAll("determinant:", "");
String endElement = tokenizer.nextToken();

System.out.println(">>1"+component+" 2>>"+determinantType+" 3>>"+determinant+" 4>>"+endElement);
```

Comment: StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(test, ";"); , What is test in here ?

Comment: The entire values are in a property file it has more than 100 records which should be split-ed  :(